# Animate.css jQuery animate one element after another

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-animations

I am currently using the animate.css library and i am trying to add a class to one element then once that animation has ran i want to add another class to another element so it in simple terms something fades in then something else fades in afterwards.

link to library :
[Animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css)

example code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <p id="welcome-text">Welcome!</p>
    <img id="welcome-image" src="assets/img/banner">


<script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(function() {

$('#welcome-text').addClass('animated bounceInDown');

$('#welcome-text').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', fucntion() {
    $('#welcome-image').addClass('animated fadeInUpBig');
});


});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The above is the way i tried to accomplish this but it doesn't work. Im fairly new to jquery/css animations so any help appreciated!

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635056/webkitanimationend-isnt-firing-can-anyone-see-why) might answer your question!

Comment: Related: [jquery remove class after css animation played?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13884563/464709) The events are named `<prefix>TransitionEnd`, not `<prefix>AnimationEnd`.

Comment: Ive added TransitionEnd instead and still no luck?

Comment: Managed to get it working by using both of these links thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't perform an action on completion of a CSS animation.  Your other options are to use javascript `setTimeout()` function, or move the animations to JQuery, which will be easier to synchronize.  Here's an example:

```
$('#element1').fadeOut(500, function() {
    $('#element2').fadeIn(500);
});
```

fadeOut, fadeIn, and other JQuery animation functions come with a callback for when the animation is complete.  This helps quite a lot with timing.  I know this example isn't specifically your animations, but should demonstrate how it can be done.

On second glance, though, your library looks like it has callback functionality built in.  Perhaps it's not working properly because of the typo "fucntion()"?

Comment: *Unfortunately you can't perform an action on completion of a CSS animation.* Sorry, that's not true.

Comment: Heh, I've been using css3 anims for a year, wonder why I never knew of this?  Hurray for learning something new!  OK, so my guess is still the typo "fucntion()".

Comment: Well, that too, but the code in the question is also binding to the wrong events.

Comment: Corrected the typo and still not working unfortunately

Comment: Didn't know about jQuery animation this is definitely something i could use in the future so thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Creating your own jQuery plugin could be useful. Place this code right after jQuery definition:

```
$.fn.animate_css = function(animation, duration, callback) {
    if ((typeof duration !== "undefined") || (duration != null) ) {
        this.css("-webkit-animation-duration", duration+"s");
    }
    this.addClass("animated " + animation);
    this.one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', callback);
}
```

With this you are able to use it like this:

```
$(".some_element").animate_css("shake", 1.5, function() {
    $(".some_element").animate_css("flash", 2.5);
} );
```

This code starts "shake" animation with 1.5 second duration and after it starts "flash" animation with 2.5 seconds duration. For better understanding i suggest to learn how callbacks work in javascript.