# AnimationEnd hide an other div

Tags: javascript, css, animation, hide

I have an animation as an intro and when it ends i would like it to hide the wrapper of the animation, since i can't use z-index on the animation.

Here's my code:

Animation

```
<div class="overlay">
  <div id="Stage" class="pelouse2"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
</div>
```

*overlay* is the class with the z-index that need to hide when the *pelouse2* ends

javascript i'm using but doesn't seem to work so far

```
<script>
    var myBox = document.getElementById('Stage');
    var overLay = document.getElementByClassName('overlay');
    myBox.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd',function( event ) { overLay.style.display = 'none'; }, false);
</script>
```

CSS for the *overlay* class, the class for the animation (*pelouse2*) is an Edge Animate animation, i'm not sure how i could post this.

Here's the website i'm working on, if it helps you figured out what is going on.

http://pelouse.co/dev/

Thank you!

Comment: What browser are you testing in? You might try just using the regular "animationend" event.

Comment: i'm testing in Safari, but "animationend" doesn't seem to work either. The problem seems to be in the javascript, i'm a beginner at it to say the least.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WebkitAnimationEnd isn't firing. Can anyone see why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635056/webkitanimationend-isnt-firing-can-anyone-see-why)

Comment: It's an Edge Animate animation so i don't think transitionEnd would work. I'm pretty sure the problem is in the javascript.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, could you post the CSS for the animation too?

Comment: I can't really post the css since it's an Edge animate animation. But i've updated the original post with all i had to share.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, you do have one error. You're calling document.getElementByClassName() which is a function that isn't actually defined. The function is getElement**s**ByClassName(). Here's the MDN page on it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName. This returns a collection of HTML elements, so you need to change your line of code to get your overlay element to this:

```
var overLay = document.getElementsByClassName('overlay')[0];
```

Also I'm not convinced Edge animations call the animationend event. Here's a document on the Javascript API, which mentions a "complete" timeline event, but sadly doesn't seem to indicate how to hook into it. http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/edgeanimate/api/current/index.html#Events

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've modified the line like you said, it hard to know if it works since animation end is probably not supported. I've created a question over at Adobe to see if there's an alternative. I'll update this question if there is anything new.